# Selecting most recent result in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I'm trying to select the most recent row (Interest Rate `IntRate`) based on two dates. The most priority date is `EffDate` while the second is `LastMaintenance`. `EffDate` has the date the `IntRate` was put into effect. So the format has something like this, `MM/DD/YYYY`. The `LastMaintenance` column has the last time the row was altered in the format of `SYSDATE`.

For example, if I change the `IntRate` within the same day, I would get two rows in the history table. Both of which will have the same `EffDate`, but different `LastMaintenance` dates.

Right now, I'm trying to select the most recent `IntRate` based off a table which has a history of `IntRate` for a given account. So I want to select the most recent `IntRate` based upon a date. The closest `IntRate` to that date is what I want to use.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to select the most recent `IntRate` when the `EffDate` is the same, but the `DateLastMaintenance` is different.

In the picture below, How do I select the `IntRate` where the value is `null`? I want that one because even though the `EffDate` is the same, the `DateLastMaintenance` field is newer for the `null` value.

[image: Example]

I have something like this to get the most recent `EffDate` for a given AcctNbr and the date where I want the most recent value of.

```
SELECT EffDate
    FROM (SELECT *
    FROM AcctRateHist X
    WHERE X.AcctNbr = A.AcctNbr -- R.Acctnbr
    AND X.EffDate <= TO_DATE('09-26-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY') -- The date to get the most recent value for
    ORDER BY X.EffDate DESC, X.DateLastMaint DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

This will get me an `EffDate` of 9/14/2017, but when I hook this up to an outer query I get all the rows with an `EffDate` of 9/14/2017, so I need to look at the `DateLastMaintenance` column now.

I tried to select the `ROWNUM = 1`, but it get's the `IntRate` of 0.0375 and not the `null` value one (Where the `ROWNUM = 2`, which I don't get why it picks up that one..).

```
SELECT R.AcctNbr, X.EffDate, X.IntRate, X.InactiveDate, X.DateLastMaint
FROM AcctRateHist X, Rpt_Sort_Process R
WHERE X.AcctNbr = R.AcctNbr -- Just some stuff thats needed to get the AcctNbr: Ignore
AND R.QueNbr = somenum -- Just some stuff thats needed to get the AcctNbr: Ignore
AND R.ApplNbr = somenum -- Just some stuff thats needed to get the AcctNbr: Ignore
AND R.QueSubNbr = somenum -- Just some stuff thats needed to get the AcctNbr: Ignore
AND X.EffDate = (SELECT EffDate -- This gets the EffDate of 9/14/2017
                FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM AcctRateHist X
                        WHERE X.AcctNbr = A.AcctNbr -- R.Acctnbr
                        AND X.EffDate <= TO_DATE('09-26-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY') -- The date to get the most recent value for
                        ORDER BY X.EffDate DESC, X.DateLastMaint DESC)
                WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
AND ROWNUM = 1 -- This SHOULD return the IntRate of null, but doesn't
ORDER BY X.EffDate DESC, X.Datelastmaint DESC;
```

Comment: can you simplify the question? it is hard to read such a long one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use tuples:

```
(X.EffDate, X.DateLastMaint) =
    (SELECT EffDate, DateLastMaint -- This gets the EffDate of 9/14/2017
     FROM (SELECT *
           FROM AcctRateHist X
           WHERE X.AcctNbr = A.AcctNbr AND
                 X.EffDate <= DATE '2017-09-26' -- The date to get the most recent value for
           ORDER BY X.EffDate DESC, X.DateLastMaint DESC)
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Windowing functions are ideal to this task. Here's a DENSE_RANK example.

```
create table acctratehist ( acctnbr int, intrate number (9,3), effdate date, datelastmaint timestamp);

insert into acctratehist values (89, 2.125, DATE '2018-03-11', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-11 11:00:00');
insert into acctratehist values (89, 2.375, DATE '2018-03-11', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-11 15:00:00');
insert into acctratehist values (89, 2.825, DATE '2018-03-12', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-12 13:00:00');
insert into acctratehist values (52, 2.000, DATE '2018-03-11', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-11 15:00:00');
insert into acctratehist values (52, 2.333, DATE '2018-03-12', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-12 13:00:00');

select t.acctnbr, t.effdate, t.intrate
from (
  select acctnbr, intrate, effdate, dense_rank() over (partition by acctnbr, effdate order by datelastmaint desc) as dlmrank
  from acctratehist
) t
where t.dlmrank = 1
order by t.acctnbr, t.effdate
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67bb8/2)